# Add to list with operator overloading

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

Suggest I have the following classes :

```
class ListWrapper

{

     private: vector<MyItem> items;

     public : MyItem& operator+(MyItem& itm){items.push_back(itm);}

};

class MyItem
{
    private: int data;
};
```

Will it be possible to add items to MyList using operator overloading with + operator?

I.e. :

```
MyItem item1,item2,item3;
ListWrapper lw;

lw + item1 + item2+ item3;
```

I can use operator on the ListWrapper, but is there is a way to have it by multiple items like this example?

Comment: you _have_ to return something from your `+` operator. And it should be a `ListWrapper`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not having an `operator+` with side effects, because it's confusing.

Better:

```
ListWrapper& operator+=(std::initializer_list<MyItem> l) {
    items.insert(items.end(), l);
    return *this;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
lw += {item1, item2, item3};
```

Comment: What do you mean by side effects

Comment: @user3150947 modifying the object is a side effect